# How to access parent view controller if there is container view inbetween?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

How can I access Tab VC from rightmost VC(black)? I tried to use parentViewController from it but got nil.

[image]

Comment: Is Tab VC rootviewcontroller?

Comment: Yes, it's root viewcontroller. I see you want to approach from other side. But I would also like to know how to bypass container view, because I may need also to access TableVC from rightmost VC for instance.

Comment: Try to map through delegate functions.

Comment: Why you can't just add IBOutlet link to VC(black)?

Comment: @SAKrisT you mean have outlet property in Tab VC which will point to rightmost one? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a great fan of Containers, they really slow down the storyboard management in XCode.

You should be able to achieve the same result by turning all containers in simple views with a common IBOutlet to some kind of BaseViewController (you should always extend your custom BaseViewController instead of UIViewController in your classes, it gives you more flexibility for common features. Maybe you're already doing it :) ).

Then you can create a custom segue class with a perform method like this

```
-(void) perform {
    BaseViewController* source = (BaseViewController*) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController* destination = self.destinationViewController
    [source.containerView addSubview:destination];
    [source addChildViewController:destination];

    //Custom code for properly center the destination view in the container. 
    //I usually use FLKAutolayout for autolayout projects with something like this
    //[destination.view alignToView:source.view];
}
```

Draw a manual segue for the parent view controller to the "contained" view controller an give it a common identifier (something like "containerSegue").

Then in each view container view controller viewDidLoad method add:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"containerSegue" sender:self];
```

and you should be in the same situation as before.
The only difference is that you can tweak the CustomSegue by adding custom properties and configuration for destination view controller. And, thanks to addChildViewController, your child VC should now have a parentViewController.

And, most of all, your storyboard should be REALLY smoother and faster to load in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in rootViewController,

```
rootViewController.h
```

```
@interface rootViewController: UIViewController

{
}

+ (UIViewController *) sharedRootViewController;
@end
```

```
rootViewController.m
```

```
@import "rootViewController.h"

@implementation rootViewController

+ (UIViewController *) sharedRootViewController
{
    return (UIViewController *)((UIWindow *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0]).rootViewController;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
}

.
.
.
@end
```